# How to retrieve removable storage drive letter using C/C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, removable-storage

How can I get the removable drive letter so that I could create a path and copy data from PC to the removable drive?

Currently I'm using

```
_getcwd(buff,b_SIZE);
MessageBox(buff);
strncpy(Root,buff,3);
```

I have no problem if I run my software directly from the USB and it will returns to me either D: or E:, which depends on the availability I guess. But my problem is I have to run my USB program from the PC which is of course the PC's program installed in C drive, and therefore this `_getcwd` will give me C:\ drive letter.  That's why I'm looking for if there's a way to check the current removable drive letter instead.

This is the nearest I could find for my question: [Detect removable drive (e.g. USB flash drive) C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184123/detect-removable-drive-e-g-usb-flash-drive-c-c)

Comment: How does that other question not answer yours?

Comment: What if there are 5 removable drives plugged in? Maybe it would be best for the user to choose.

Comment: Hi @Dialecticus will be only 1. Because this is a machine which using windows. Or i would say i will make sure 1 removable drive only. Thanks

Comment: @Jongware Yes i couldn't understand the solution given. Especially how to use the structure dbcv_unitmask to return the drive letter?

Comment: the [first answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/286555/33499) also answers your question.

Comment: I perhaps in my case i should count the last one as my removable drive? As there's no other drive plugging in after me.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to determine which removable drive was plugged in last. Such information is probably not kept available in the system. There are ways to detect changes while they happen, but I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: "*... was plugged in last.*": @Dialecticus: One could scan the event logs?

Comment: @alk true. Would have to translate the full USB device name to drive letter, and hope that event log is not cleared, but apart from that it looks doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GetLogicalDrives()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364972.aspx) will give you all the drives that are currently available. Loop through given bit-vector (bit 0 is drive A:, bit 1 is drive B:, etc.) and for each available drive check if [GetDriveType()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364939.aspx) returns `DRIVE_REMOVABLE`.

Or, you can just skip GetLogicalDrives(), and loop through all 26 letters of the alphabet, looking for `DRIVE_REMOVABLE`.

Comment: Okay! I can understand this. Let me try thanks !

Comment: ya i can get the drive letter now. But couldn't differentiate if it is a storage removable media. I'm currently starting my loop from C: onwards just to avoid the possibility of floopy drives on A: or B:.